# Cancellation Exception in SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm trying to cancel a function from a button click on a JFrame form.

Here is my worker function:

```
private void start(final Callable<Void> func) {
        worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                publish(2);
                func.call();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                boolean status;
                try {
                    status = get();
                    dialog.dispose();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    progressBar.setString("ERROR");
                    Logger.getLogger(Parser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

            }

        };
```

This is what i tried to cancel the SwingWorker object:

```
   dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
{

  @Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
  {

    worker.cancel(true);

  }
});
```

But when i click on close button, it gives me exception and `func` is not cancelled inside `doinBackground()` method. How can i stop `func` method?

Comment: how should the func know that it is being cancelled? As a general rule, the doInBackground has to cooperate (that is look out for being cancelled and stop whatever it's doing) - no idea how-to apply that rule here, though ;-)

Comment: Well, does that mean it's impossible to cancel doInBackground op?

Comment: no, but you have to _do_ it ...

Answer (score 2):

After a pitiful misunderstanding about [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) interfaces (so sorry, I have to leave JDBC for a while :P) the point I've made still valid (fortunately). You might use [SwingWorker#isCancelled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#isCancelled%28%29) method within [done()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29) implementation like this:

```
@Override
protected void done() {
    if(isCancelled()) {
        try {
            func.cancel(); // you need to provide this method
            dialog.dispose();
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
             progressBar.setString("ERROR");
             Logger.getLogger(Parser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you'll need to provide a `cancel()` method to your callable implementation which could be easy or hard depending on what `call()` method is actually doing. For example:

```
abstract class AbstractCancellableTask<T> implements Callable<T> {

    public abstract void cancel() throws InterruptedException;
}
```

---

#### Example

I have updated my previous example using `Callable`. Note the task is cancelled when `worker.cancel(true)` method is invoked.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Demo {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        final SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            private AbstractCancellableTask<Void> myCallable;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                myCallable = new AbstractCancellableTask<Void>() {

                    private volatile boolean flag = true;

                    @Override
                    public void cancel() throws InterruptedException {
                        flag = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        while(flag) {
                            System.out.println("Running heavy task...");

                        }
                        System.out.println("Stopped!");
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                myCallable.call();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                if(isCancelled()) {
                    try {
                        myCallable.cancel();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton("Start...", false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JToggleButton toggleButton = (JToggleButton)e.getSource();
                if(toggleButton.isSelected()) {
                    worker.execute();
                    toggleButton.setText("Stop it!");
                } else {
                    worker.cancel(true);
                    toggleButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.add(button);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    abstract class AbstractCancellableTask<T> implements Callable<T> {

        public abstract void cancel() throws InterruptedException;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for example but There is no cancel() method for my function.

Comment: should i create another class for my background operations?

Comment: Oh I made a terrible mistake :( You're using [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) not [CallableStament](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) interface... too much work with databases I see JDBC everywhere... Sorry about that! *But* the main concept still valid, you might use `SwingWorker#isCancelled()` and provide your `func` with some `cancel` method. It's not going to be easy though... @AloneInTheDark

Comment: Please see my update. Hope it be more helpful this time :) @AloneInTheDark

Comment: So the key is putting a "while" statement and check with a boolean flag?

Comment: No, the key is actually provide a `cancel()` method. It's just an example of implementation. In this case the heavy task is a loop printing a string till `flag` be false. That only will happen when some outside object calls `cancel()` method setting `flag` to false, which only will happen when SwingWorker is cancelled. Do I make myself clear? Please let me know if don't. @AloneInTheDark

Comment: how can i run my function(which belongs to another class) inside this mycallable?

Comment: Do you have the code that is executed in your function? If so then you can create a new `AbstractCancellableTask` and put that code in `call()` method implementation. Then you'll have to manage how-to cancel the execution of that code (if possible). If you don't have that code and you receive just a callable function from the outside then I'm afraid you won't be able to accomplish your goal. @AloneInTheDark

Comment: I have the code but the problem is it's too complicated that it calls objects from another classes and some gui objects. I may try your solution but it'll take lots of time from me... Thanks anyway.

Comment: You're welcome! As I've said it could be easy or hard depending on what has to be done. Hope it be the first option ;) @AloneInTheDark

Comment: @AloneInTheDark _some gui objects_ accessing the view in doInBackground, so your function **must not**!